# Change text when radio button is checked

Tags: css, radio-button, checked

i can change the color of the "vote-icon" when the radio button is checked but i can't change the color of the "radio-text". Any help will be appreciated.

```
  <div class="vote-answers"  id="poll-vote-{{$choice->id}}">
     <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choiceId" value="{{$choice->id}}">
           <span class="vote-icon"></span>
           <span class="radio-text">{{$choice->show($poll)}}</span>
      </label>
    </div>


 #poll-vote-id {
    label > input:checked + span.vote-icon:after,
    label > input:checked + span.radio-text { 
      color: #3f75c7;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `+` combinator means the very next element **the adjacent sibling selector**..which the `.radio-text` element is not.

Use the `~` selector instead...this is the **general sibling selector**.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048